# create php array from paragraphs inside a varaible

Tags: php, arrays

I have a set of paragraphs that are inside a variable that I'd like to add to an array.

so...

```
$text = 
'<p>para 1</p>
<p>para 2</p>
<p>para 3</p>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
  [0] => para 1
  [1] => para 2
  [2] => para 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the actual implementation. For a simple list like this which have a consisten format I'd just `str_replace` the `<p>` and `</p>`, and then `explode` by newline.

If you however are trying to more than this with HTML in general, I suggest reading into [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to properly parse and manipulate your HTML.

Comment: Ok so the context is that Im using wordpress and a metabox where the user can enter content. I then want to see how many paragraphs there are and put an image in the halfway point.

So im creating the array so I can calculate half way and be able to add the image in.

Comment: Well if you're dealing with user supplied content then I definitely suggest using the _tool that is made for that job_, so DOMDocument or any other HTML-parsing library that you fancy. With DOMDocument there are ways to iterate over the elements and do some magic that way. Might be a bit steeper to learn than str_replace, but definitely a useful tool to learn imho.
And just as a side-note, please escape all output that is supplied by users that you don't trust.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the `<p>` tag with empty

```
$text = 
'<p>para 1</p>
<p>para 2</p>
<p>para 3</p>';

$text = str_replace("<p>", '', $text);
//output is
// $text = 'para 1</p>para 2</p>para 3</p>';
$array = explode($text);

Array
(
  [0] => para 1
  [1] => para 2
  [2] => para 3
)
```